# how to display multi results using loop in ejs template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

screenshots: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8z5M.png)

my code:
(ejs file code)

```
<div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Domain Age Checker</h1>``
      <form action="/domainagechecker" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="domain">Domain URL:</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            type="text"
            name="domain"
            id=""
            placeholder="write a domain"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Get Details</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />

      <%if (flag) { %>

      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Domain Name</th>
            <th>Running Server</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Domain Age</th>
            <th>Last Renewal</th>
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><%=data.domainName%></td>
            <td><%=data.registrar%></td>
            <td><%=date%></td>
            <td><%=domainAge%></td>
            <td><%=data.updatedDate%></td>
            <td><%=data.registryExpiryDate%></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   <% } %>
</div>
```

***(node js apis:)

---

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.render("domainagechecker", {
      title: "Domain Details",
      data: "",
      flag: false,
      date: "",
      domainAge: "",
    });
})

app.post("/domainagechecker", async (req, res) => {
  var domain = req.body.domain;
  console.log(domain);

  var list_Domains = domain.split(" ");

  for (let i = 0; i < list_Domains.length; i++) {
    console.log("sl.no " + i + " " + list_Domains[i]);

    if (isValidDomain(list_Domains[i])) {
      var result = await whoisinfo(list_Domains[i]);
      console.log(result);

      var date = moment(result.creationDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      var curDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");

      console.log("creation date: " + date);
      console.log(curDate);

      var a = moment(date);
      var b = moment(curDate);
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);

      var years = b.diff(a, "years");
      a.add(years, "years");

      var months = b.diff(a, "months");
      a.add(months, "months");

      var days = b.diff(a, "days");

      var domainAge =
        years + " years " + months + " months and " + days + " days";

      res.render("domainagechecker", {
        title: "Domain Details",
        data: result,
        flag: true,
        date: date,
        domainAge: domainAge,
        domain1: domain,
      });
    } else {
      res.send("please enter domain name as 'example.com' (only domain name)");
    }
  }
});
```

I have tried with for loop, but it won't work for me. Please let me know solutions.

API is fetching results as per inputs, but ejs template displays only the first value. Help me to get results for multiple inputs in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're rendering one by one and taking result one time, instead of this put all the data inside Array then you will be reaching all data

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("domainagechecker", {
        title: "Domain Details",
        results: [],
        flag: false,
    });
});
```

then push all data :

```
results.push({
  domainName: list_Domains[i],
  data: result,
  date: date,
  domainAge: domainAge,
});
```

your final ejs should be rendering full of data inside results Array :

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Domain Name</th>
      <th>Running Server</th>
      <th>Creation Date</th>
      <th>Domain Age</th>
      <th>Last Renewal</th>
      <th>Expiry Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% results.forEach(function(result) { %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= result.domainName %></td>
      <td><%= result.data.registrar %></td>
      <td><%= result.date %></td>
      <td><%= result.domainAge %></td>
      <td><%= result.data.updatedDate %></td>
      <td><%= result.data.registryExpiryDate %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

nodejs :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('domainagechecker', {
    title: 'Domain Details',
    results: [],
    flag: false,
  });
});

app.post('/domainagechecker', async (req, res) => {
  var domain = req.body.domain;
  console.log(domain);

  var list_Domains = domain.split(' ');

  var results = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list_Domains.length; i++) {
    console.log('sl.no ' + i + ' ' + list_Domains[i]);

    if (isValidDomain(list_Domains[i])) {
      var result = await whoisinfo(list_Domains[i]);
      console.log(result);

      var date = moment(result.creationDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      var curDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      console.log('creation date: ' + date);
      console.log(curDate);

      var a = moment(date);
      var b = moment(curDate);
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);

      var years = b.diff(a, 'years');
      a.add(years, 'years');

      var months = b.diff(a, 'months');
      a.add(months, 'months');

      var days = b.diff(a, 'days');

      var domainAge = years + ' years ' + months + ' months and ' + days + ' days';

      results.push({
        domainName: list_Domains[i],
        data: result,
        date: date,
        domainAge: domainAge,
      });
    } else {
      res.send("please enter domain name as 'example.com' (only domain name)");
      return; // Stop execution if validation fails
    }
  }

  res.render('domainagechecker', {
    title: 'Domain Details',
    results: results,
    flag: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you, very clerly mentioned. it's working.